# Which MVVMCross Package contains the WindowsStore namespace

Tags: nuget, mvvmcross

After updating an MVVMCross project from 3.1.1 to 3.2.1, I found that I was getting errors resolving the references to MvxStorePage (Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.Views).

I've had a look inside the MVVMCross project, and it looks like WindowsStore should be inside Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.dll.  However, I can't seem to determine which NuGet package this is.  I've tried looking in the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/), but can't seem to determine where it is.

I'm currently referencing:

MMVMCross
MMVMCross - MVVMCrossCore
MMVMCross - MVVMCrossCore - Portable Support
MVVMCross - Hot Tuna Libraries
MVVMCross - Hot Tuna Starter Pack
+ A bunch of plug-ins

So, my question is twofold: which package is this located in and, as a wider question, how can I determine myself which package it's in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages are defined in nuspec files in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/3.2/nuspec

You can see which ones reference `Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.dll` using search - e.g. GitHub search https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.dll&type=Code or download the files and use `grep` or `Find in Files` locally

Comment: If your project is a Windows8.1 project (not Windows 8.0) then Mvx has switched to WindowsCommon from WindowsStore... if you need to know more... blame Microsoft :/